# How to migrate modify a collections of object array in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database-migration, mongoose-schema

I have the following schema mongoose, but have a app in production with collections. This is a simplification of a much larger problem, reduced for better understanding.

**This is only a sample basic.**

```
export const ListSchema = new Schema({
  listaItemsIds: [
    {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Items',
        default: [],
    },
  ],
});
```

**I need to migrate all the data to the following model.**

```
export const ListSchema = new Schema({
  listaItemsIds: [
    {
      item: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Items',
        default: [],
      },
      property1: {
        type: Number,
        required: false,
        default: 0,
      },
      property2: {
        type: Number,
        required: false,
        default: 0,
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

**The following document**

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("62bade11ff94fb9e5a0f5236"),
        "listaItemsIds" : [
                ObjectId("62a118a9167d269d38a4c806"),
                ObjectId("62baef0cff94fb9e5a0f53e3"),
                ObjectId("627bb4d61119d5ce2201b7df")
        ],
        "__v" : 37
}
```

**it is necessary to transform**

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("62bade11ff94fb9e5a0f5236"),
        "listaItemsIds" : [
                {
                    item:ObjectId("62a118a9167d269d38a4c806"),
                    property1:55,
                    property2:75,
                },
                {
                    item:ObjectId("62baef0cff94fb9e5a0f53e3"),
                    property1:55,
                    property2:75,
                },
                {
                    item:ObjectId("627bb4d61119d5ce2201b7df"),
                    property1:55,
                    property2:75,
                },              
        ],
        "__v" : 37
}
```

I have tried the following code snippet with no results.

```
db.ListSchemas.updateMany({},
    [
    {$set: {"listaItemsIds.$[elem]":
    {
      item:"listaItemsIds.$[elem]",
      property1:0,
      property2:0,
    }}}
    ]
    );
```

Surely someone with more experience can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
{
$addFields: {
  listaItemsIds: {
    $map: {
      input: "$listaItemsIds",
      as: "id",
      in: {
          item: "$$id",
          property1: 55,
          property2: 75
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

Explained:

Replace the array using $map to create the necessary objects.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oF-O5JrjGMg)